# ADAL Authentication issue: sign in page presented in loop on android 7.0

Tags: authentication, xamarin.android, adal

We are using microsoft.identitymodel.clients.activedirectory library for authentication in our xamarin.Android app. Authentication is not working on android 7.0 devices. We are not able to enter password as the sign in page is presented in a loop.

The expectation is once we provide the username (somename@microsoft.com) it should redirect to a screen where it ask for password. In our case it never redirect to this screen.

We are using microsoft.identitymodel.clients.activedirectory 3.16.1

If we try to debug the code the AcquireTokenAsync() method never return the result.

**Edit:** Here is the Code:

```
 public async Task<string> Authenticate(Android.App.Activity activity, bool prompt)
        {
            AuthenticationResult AResult;
            AuthenticationContext context = new AuthenticationContext(AdalIssuerAuthority);
            PlatformParameters prametrs = new PlatformParameters(activity);
            try
            {

                if (prompt)
                {
                    AResult = await context.AcquireTokenAsync(AdalResourceId, AdalClientId, _returnUri, prametrs);
                }
                else
                {
                    AResult = await context.AcquireTokenSilentAsync(AdalResourceId, AdalClientId);
                }

                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(AResult.AccessToken))
                {
                    AResult = await context.AcquireTokenAsync(AdalResourceId, AdalClientId, _returnUri, prametrs);
                }

                if (AResult.AccessToken != null)
                {
                    Constants.szUserName = AResult.UserInfo.GivenName + " " + AResult.UserInfo.FamilyName;
                    Constants.Token = Constants.ADALAccessToken;
                    Constants.szUserAlias = Constants.szUserAlias;
                }

                return AResult.AccessToken;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //logging excepton here
            }
        }
```

Code from Login Activity:

```
 protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, Result resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        try
        {
            base.OnActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            AuthenticationAgentContinuationHelper.SetAuthenticationAgentContinuationEventArgs(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //log exception
        }
    }
```

Comment: @Graham Thanks for helping, added the code.

Answer (score 0):

I too got the same issue.

The step to override the OnActivityResult() was missed

Please add the below to MainActivity.cs ( Android project)

```
protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, Result resultCode, Intent data)
{
    base.OnActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    AuthenticationAgentContinuationHelper.SetAuthenticationAgentContinuationEventArgs(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```